# How can I get a list of available serial ports using 'serial.tools.list_ports' python module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I'm new to python and I need a list of available serial ports to choose one of them in a program. According to [This](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#module-serial.tools.list_ports), the `serial.tools.list_ports` module can do that for me by executing `serial.tools.list_ports.comports()` method. Accordingly,I executed the following code in python interpreter:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
a=serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
print(a)
```

the result is:

```
[<serial.tools.list_ports_linux.SysFS object at 0x7f2503d27be0>]
```

while when I use the following command in `ubuntu` terminal

```
python3 -m serial.tools.list_ports
```

it returns what I want:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0        
1 ports found
```

where is the problem?

Comment: What does `print(a[0])` output?

Comment: Thanks! It worked .We should access to the object attributes like `name`, `device` and ... .In pyserial docs it said the output is a `ListPortInfo` object. but here is `SysFs` and it has no `__bases__` attribute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the documentation you've linked,

> The function returns a list of [ListPortInfo](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#serial.tools.list_ports.ListPortInfo) objects.

They have several attributes which you can use, for example `device`:

> Full device name/path, e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0`

In order to emulate the command `python3 -m serial.tools.list_ports`, you could do:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
for p in ports:
    print(p.device)
print(len(ports), 'ports found')
```

<sub>Which is a simplified version of what it [actually does](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/tools/list_ports.py#L85).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

An easier way that returns list (using answers above/below) is using .device while iterating through the list of ports obtained from list_ports.comports()

eg.

```
ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
# 'com_list' contains list of all com ports

com_list = []

for p in ports:
    com_list.append(p.device)
```