# Python code error to connect to COM Port connected to relay

Tags: python, serial-port, serial-communication, relay

I am trying to turn a Relay on or off using python. The relay is from Numado. I am using the following simple code.

```
portName = "COM4";
relayNum = 0;
relayCmd = "on";

#Open port for communication
serPort = serial.Serial(portName, 19200, timeout=1)

#Send the command
serPort.write("relay "+ relayCmd +" "+ str(relayNum) + "\n\r")

print("Command sent...")

#Close the port
serPort.close()
```

However, this is not working. The error i get is this:

*serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': FileNotFoundError(2, 'Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.', None, 2)*

Could somebody please tell me where I am going wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a list of available serial ports using 'serial.tools.list\_ports' python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324545/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-available-serial-ports-using-serial-tools-list-ports-p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the port "COM4" doesn't exist. Where did you get that number from? Check if you can find it in Windows Device Manager.

Comment: Yes. It does exist on the system